# Extract cities from each row in excel and export to its respective row using R

Tags: r, tweets

I have extracted tweets in .csv format and the data looks like this:

```
(row 1) The latest The Admin Resources Daily! Thanks to @officerenegade @roberthalf @elliottdotorg #airfare #jobsearch
(row 2) RT @airfarewatchdog: Los Angeles #LAX to Cabo #SJD $312 nonstop on @AmericanAir for summer travel. #airfare
(row 3) RT @TheFlightDeal: #Airfare Deal: [AA] New York - Mexico City, Mexico. $270 r/t. Details:
(row 4) The latest The Nasir Muhammad Daily! Thanks to @Matt_Revel @Roddee @JaeKay #lefforum #airfare
(row 5) RT @BarefootNomads: So cool! <U+2708> <U+2764><U+FE0F> #airfare deals w @Skyscanner Facebook Messenger Bot #traveldeals #cheapflights ht…
(row 6) Flights to #Oranjestad #Aruba are £169 for a 15 day trip departing Tue, Jun 7th. #airfare via @hitlist_app"
```

I have made use of the NLP technique to extract city names from the tweets but the output is a list of cities with each city occupying a row one below the other. It is just identifying all the city names and making a list of it.

```
Output: 
1   Los Angeles
2   New York
3   Mexico City
4   Mexico
5   Tue
6   London
7   New York
8   Fort Lauderdale
9   Los Angeles
10  Paris
```

I want the output to be something like:

```
1  Los Angeles Cabo (from the first tweet in row 2)
2  New York Mexico City Mexico (from the second tweet in row 3)
```

Code:

```
#Named Entity Recognition (NER)

bio <- readLines("C:\\xyz\\tweets.csv")
print(bio)

install.packages(c("NLP", "openNLP", "RWeka", "qdap"))

install.packages("openNLPmodels.en",
             repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at/",
             type = "source")

library(NLP)
library(openNLP)
library(RWeka)
library(qdap)
library(openNLPmodels.en)
library(magrittr)

bio <- as.String(bio)

word_ann <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
sent_ann <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()

bio_annotations <- annotate(bio, list(sent_ann, word_ann))

class(bio_annotations)
head(bio_annotations)

bio_doc <- AnnotatedPlainTextDocument(bio, bio_annotations)
sents(bio_doc) %>% head(2)
words(bio_doc) %>% head(10)

location_ann <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator(kind = "location")

pipeline <- list(sent_ann,
                 word_ann,
                 location_ann)
bio_annotations <- annotate(bio, pipeline)
bio_doc <- AnnotatedPlainTextDocument(bio, bio_annotations)

entities <- function(doc, kind) {
  s <- doc$content
  a <- annotations(doc)[[1]]
  if(hasArg(kind)) {
    k <- sapply(a$features, `[[`, "kind")
    s[a[k == kind]]
  } else {
    s[a[a$type == "entity"]]
  }
}   

entities(bio_doc, kind = "location")
cities <- entities(bio_doc, kind = "location")

library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(cities, "C:\\xyz\\xyz.xlsx")
```

Also is there a way that I can further separate the cities as origin and destination, i.e. by classifying cities before 'to' or '-' as origin cities and the rest as destination cities?

Comment: Maybe `df$cities <- lapply(df$tweets, function(tweet){cities[sapply(cities, function(city){grepl(city, tweet)})]})`. It makes a list column, but you can either expand it or `paste` it together if you prefer.